# How to prevent rewrite data in array while looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

What I like is an Array like this

```
myArray = [
  [{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}]
  [{"value":2},{"value":4},{"value":6}]
]
```

I try to use two loops to build it. The outer loop shout build the two "outer" Elements in Array, the inner loop shout build the 3 inner objects.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtrem1234/xx06zt5s/

```js
var dataset = [];
var categories = ["Category_1", "Category_2"];
var myArray = [];

categories.forEach(function (category, index) { 
            
    for (var n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
        var d;
        d = {};
        d.value = (index+1) * n;
        console.log("index: " + index);
        console.log("n: " + n);
        console.log("d.value: " + d.value);

        dataset[n] = d; 
                
                
    }

    myArray.push(dataset);
     
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Comment: That thing you like up the top, thats an awful structure for data. An array, with embedded arrays, and each embedded array has objects with a single property. What would that even represent?

Comment: Another issue you will run into is that your `dataset[n]` will always start at 1, whereas an array starts at an index of 0.

Comment: try `for (var n = 0; n < 3; n++)` instead

Comment: the inner loop stands for creating an array out of an responsive dataset - to make it simple

Comment: All answers helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, your array `dataset` is a global array. Define it inside `forEach` loop.

#### Code

```js
var categories = ["Category_1", "Category_2"];
var myArray = [];

categories.forEach(function(category, index) {
  var dataset = [];
  for (var n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
    var d;
    d = {};
    d.value = (index + 1) * n;
    dataset[n] = d;
  }

  myArray.push(dataset);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

A: you need to reinitialize the dataset array each time the forEach loop runs

B: you can just push() the info to the dataset array, the same way you do for myArray

```
var categories = ["Category_1", "Category_2"];
var myArray = [];

categories.forEach(function (category, index) { 
  var dataset = [];
  for (var n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
    dataset.push({'value': (index+1) * n});
  }
  myArray.push(dataset);            
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```